# Web page is not getting loaded for second url in protractor testing. If we test for two urls consecutively

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am testing an angular application and the folder structure for my test files are as mentioned below:

Main application folder --> test --> e2e --> forms

And now I have two folders under above path as "x" & "Y" and some test files (.ts) in both the folders.

When I run my tests which are available in both the folders. Only the test files which are in "x" folders are getting executed correctly. But the web page is not getting loaded for the files which are in "Y" folder.

Please note, there are two different urls. . All the test files in "x" folder has same url and all the test files in "Y" folder has same url.

I am reloading my web page after every test. And for this I am using ptor.get(url) in beforeEach function. (ptor = protractor.getInsance())

Please note, It was working earlier and stopped working all of sudden. Do not why, I have not made any changes in my test files.

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ptor.get(url) and replaced this with browser.get(url) and it started working for me. Also i was using "ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;" in beforeEach() method, I removed this as well. Now everything is working fine.